# What is wrong with this algorithm? (Java)

Tags: java, for-loop

I need help with this problem. I already did it, but there is an error and I can't identify which is.

Suppose that you have a ball that can be divided into smaller balls. Those balls have integer sizes starting at 1. A ball of size W>1 will produce another ball of size (W−1) every W^2 minutes. For instance, a ball of size 3 will assemble another of size 2 every 9 minutes. Production starts from the moment that the ball is created. Balls of size 1 are too small to create others. In addition, a ball of size W is limited to assembling W smaller balls as a safety precaution.

Input Format

The input will begin with an integer Z denoting the number of test cases. Each case will consist of a single line containing an integer W, indicating the size of the initial ball.

Constraints
1≤Z≤1000 
1≤W≤20

Output Format

For each test case, output a single line containing a pair of integers X and Y, separated by one space. The integer X will indicate the total amount of balls left after allowing them to replicate as much as possible. The integer Y will indicate the number of minutes that it would take for the balls to finish replicating. The order of the results must follow the same order in which the test cases are provided.

Sample Input

2

1

3

Sample Output

1 0

10 35

Explanation

In the first case, the initial size-1 ball cannot replicate. There is 1 ball in the end and the time required to reach that number is 0 minutes. In the second case, the original size-3 ball produces size-2 balls, which then produce more size-1 balls. The initial ball needs 9 minutes to create a smaller robot, then another 9 minutes pass before the second one, and so on. Each size-2 ball starts assembling smaller balls as soon as it's created. There are 10 balls once the replication process finishes and it takes 35 minutes in total.

This is my first try.

```
public class Solution {

    private static Scanner STDIN = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int t = STDIN.nextInt();

        for(int k = 0; k<t; k++){

            int n = STDIN.nextInt();
            int factor = 1;
            int balls = 1;
            int time = 0;

            for(int i=n; i>1; i--){
                factor*=i;
                balls+=factor;
                time+=Math.pow(i,3);
            }
            System.out.println(balls+" "+time);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you tell what are the outputs you are getting with your approach? Looks like you will get the correct output.

Comment: I am getting the correct result in a lot of cases, but there are a few that I am missing and I dont know which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your solution might be failing in cases where the number of balls exceed the range of integer. Try using `long` type for `factor` , `balls`, `type`.

Comment: Done! It was! Thank you! (: